# Copy and Paste Entire Row

Tags: vba, excel, copy

**Function:** I am working on a small project where I need to search each cell in a column for the word "Unknown" if it contains that word then copy that entire row on to a new sheet.

**Problem:** I am getting the "Object doesn't support this property method." error. I believe it is somewhere within the copy statement (not destination). It so simple but I cannot seem to solve this issue.

```
Sub CheckRows()
Dim b As Range
Dim SrchRng As Range

Set b = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1")
Set SrchRng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("G1")

Do While SrchRng.Value <> ""     
    If SrchRng.Value = "Unknown" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet 1").SrchRng.EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet 2").b
        Set b = b.Offset(1, 0)
        Set SrchRng = SrchRng.Offset(1, 0)
    Else: Set SrchRng = SrchRng.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: When you get the error, hold the CTRL key down and press the PAUSE/BREAK key.  It may prompt you to enter the Debugger.  If it does, press the DEBUG button.  It should highlight the exact line of code that's causing the error.  Can you tell us which line of code is highlighted?

Comment: Though a `Do While` loop can achieve your goal of copying rows that match "Unknown" in column G, using Excel's built-in `.Autofilter` method is probably a better choice as you can grab all the matching rows in one swoop. Here's an MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: SrchRng already includes a reference to ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1"), so I think you can just use SrchRng.EntireRow.Copy etc. Similarly with b.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. It has been awhile since I have last used VBA so I have gotten rusty and this help shake the cobwebs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Range.EntireRow.Value` Property

```
b.EntireRow.Value = SrchRng.EntireRow.Value
```

In

```
Do While SrchRng.Value <> ""
    If SrchRng.Value = "Unknown" Then
      b.EntireRow.Value = SrchRng.EntireRow.Value
    Set b = b.Offset(1, 0)
    Set SrchRng = SrchRng.Offset(1, 0)
    Else: Set SrchRng = SrchRng.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Wow this was such an easy fix! This is the first time I have touched VBA in a year so I forgot about small work around like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following situation:

[image: start-1]
[image: start-2]

`Sheet 1` has a block of data, with "Unknown" entries in column G, and `Sheet 2` is empty.

By defining the block of data as a `Range` object and applying an `.Autofilter` that identifies the "Unknown" entries we can simply copy over the filtered results to `Sheeet 2`. The following heavily-commented script does just that:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CheckRowsWithAutofilter()

Dim DataBlock As Range, Dest As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim SheetOne As Worksheet, SheetTwo As Worksheet

'set references up-front
Set SheetOne = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1")
Set SheetTwo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2")
Set Dest = SheetTwo.Cells(1, 1) '<~ this is where we'll put the filtered data

'identify the "data block" range, which is where
'the rectangle of information that we'll apply
'.autofilter to
With SheetOne
    LastRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set DataBlock = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
End With

'apply the autofilter to column G (i.e. column 7)
With DataBlock
    .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=*Unknown*"
    'copy the still-visible cells to sheet 2
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Dest
End With

'turn off the autofilter
With SheetOne
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    If .FilterMode = True Then .ShowAllData
End With

End Sub
```

Here is the output on `Sheet 2`:

[image: end]

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation I had no idea about the autofilter function. I will have to keep this in my bag of tools from now on :)

Comment: Glad I could help -- it's a really handy tool because it operates the same way many users would operate given the same challenge, and it allows you to skip looping in many situations

Comment: This code fails with there is allot of data in sheet1 at this line

.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Dest

Is there a workaround? (1 million rows)

Comment: 1 million rows is very close to Excel's row limit. Two questions: (1) does this large file open successfully, and (2) what is the error?